# After setting up a subsite, how to change template to same as default but showing diff catalog?

Tags: catalog, template, multistore, design

I have several subsites that I've set up on a site I've inherited where there needs to be several sites with differing domains.

I found [this tutorial](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-multi-site-multi-domain-setup) and these two screencasts ([Part 1](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-creating-multiple-online-storefronts-part1/) & [Part 2](http://www.magentocommerce.com/blog/comments/video-creating-multiple-online-storefronts-part-2/)) very helpful, however I am not finding a way to apply the same template design of the main default site to these subsites.  The goal is to use the same design for all of the sites with primarily simply a different root category for the subsites.

To give this context I have something like `MainStore.tld` and then `MensShoes.tld`, `OutdoorSupplies.tld`, etc. and I simply want make `MensShoes.tld` to look like `MainStore.tld`, but to have a different catalog base so as to have different products and perhaps some different elements such as slide images, images, etc.

How is this scenario usually configured in Magento?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I following the question completely, so apologies if this is off base, but you should just be able to use the `System -> Configuration -> Design` section to set a default theme for all stores, and then set a specific `template` theme folder for the other stores.

[image]

Use the store switcher in the upper left hand corner to select an appropriate scope

[image]